# What validation is important in a PHP web form that only interacts with itself?

Tags: php, base64, security

I made a simple base64 decoder form, which takes in an input through a textarea.  I assume the input is base64 encoded.  If it isn't base64 input, and there's a PHP error or garbage is returned, I don't mind at the moment  However, from a security perspective do I need to do any validation or sanitation on this input?

The page is called error-decoder.php, and it submits to itself, and doesn't interact with a database or anything else.  Here is the whole thing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; font-family: sans-serif;">

            <form name="error-decoder" action="error-decoder.php" method="post">
                <textarea name="error-text-area" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
                    <?php if(!empty($_POST['error-text-area'])){ echo $_POST['error-text-area']; } ?>
                </textarea>
                <button type="submit" style="float: right;">Decode</button>
            </form>

            <?php
            if(!empty($_POST['error-text-area'])){
            ?>
                <p>Output:</p>
                <hr>
                <div id="error-output">
                <br />
            <?php
                echo base64_decode($_POST['error-text-area']) . "</div>";
            }
            ?>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Is there anything that needs to be done to make this safe either for the user or for my server?  Are there important php.ini settings I need to worry about that would affect your answer?  I don't care about errors or garbage except how it might affect security.  Thanks for any info on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using POST, so cross-site scripting is not possible, however local HTML/script injection *is* possible. The only security hole involves a user shooting themselves in the foot: If they submit base64 encoded malicious HTML/JS, they might end up redirecting themselves to a malicious page. So, sanitize the output of the decoding function.

Comment: That is, it has similar "security implications" to a site like jsfiddle.net approximately (+1). *However*, I wonder if it really is expecting to decode HTML ..

Comment: @Sven: Thanks for the edit, but I want to differentiate between cross-site scripting and local JavaScript injection.

Comment: @pst: Good comparison. `... if it really is expecting to decode HTML` - Exactly!

Answer (score 4):

When you output to html, you should use `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid that your data breaks the html. Unless you are outputting html itself of course.

So:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(base64_decode($_POST['error-text-area']));
```

Comment: The same applies for pre-filling the textarea - needs also escaping.

Comment: @Sven Yep, I missed that one, but all output to html that is not supposed to be html should pass through `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: @Ninsuo No, depending on the page encoding, some characters might not display correctly, but as far as security is concerned, you only need to take care of the characters that have a special significance in html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since the output for that is used for HTML viewing, it needs to be encoded as HTML. A simple pass through `htmlentities()` solves that problem.

The actual vulnerability is that someone may inject `<script>` tags or similar hazardous tags to your page, and affect the page.

Comment: But this is allowed all the time on sites like jsfiddle .. that is, if the *user* enters it, is it really an issue that can/should be guarded against? (I am making the assumption that the user knows about this implication, which could be false, but should be included in an answer that uses the reasoning provided.)

Comment: Using htmlentities() requires passing the correct encoding of the string. htmlspecialchars() theroretically has the same requirement, but in reality only affects safe ASCII characters.

Comment: @pst On js fiddle, you see the code, i.e. the script tags and all, before/as you put it in.  if it's base64, you can't till it decodes it.

Comment: So similar to running a program that looks like [one of these](http://www.ioccc.org/) .. but what if *you* wrote it? I like where this answer (and your last comment) is going, but I think it misses some defining of *when* and *why* this operation is "unsafe".